# Try to extract one example from Superscrollorama page, Please help~!

Tags: superscrollorama

I am trying to write simplified `javascript` to run a specific example from [a link](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/).

The example I want to use is the 'showcase' section where the title, 'showcase' fades in and the images appear. I wish to extract related html and javascript to run that.

I downloaded the example file and managed to cut down unnecessary html.

```
<div id="showcase">
        <h1>Showcase</h1>
        <p>Check out these great websites to see SuperScrollorama in action</p>
        <div class="gallery clearfix">
            <figure>
                <a href="http://www.zivotjednekuchyne.cz">
                    <img src="gallery/ikea.jpg" alt="Ikea, Life of One Kitchen">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Ikea, Life of One Kitchen<br />
                    <small><a href="http://www.smashingawards.com/design/life-of-one-kitchen/">Smashing Award Winner</a></small>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="http://lifeisvertical.alpina-since1883.com">
                    <img src="gallery/alpina.jpg" alt="Alpina - Life Is Vertical">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Alpina - Life Is Vertical<br />
                    <small><a href="http://www.cssdesignawards.com/css-web-design-award-winner.php?id=20048">CSS Design Award Winner</a></small>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="http://www.nouvelleoctavia.fr">
                    <img src="gallery/skoda.jpg" alt="New Škoda Octavia">
                </a>
                <figcaption>New Škoda Octavia<br />
                    <small><a href="http://cssawards.net/new-skoda-octavia/">CSS Awards Site of the Day</a></small>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="https://corporate.target.com/about/design-innovation/owned-brands/">
                    <img src="gallery/target.jpg" alt="Target Exclusive Brands Site">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Target Exclusive Brands</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="http://www.zippergaleria.com.br/pt/">
                    <img src="gallery/zipper.jpg" alt="Zipper Galleria">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Zipper Galleria<br />
                    <small><a href="http://www.awwwards.com/web-design-awards/zipper-galeria">Awwwards Site of the Day Winner</a></small>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="http://inception-explained.com">
                    <img src="gallery/inception.jpg" alt="Inception Explained">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Inception Explained<br />
                    <small><a href="http://designtaxi.com/news/351985/Finally-The-Complex-Plot-of-Inception-Explained/">Featured on TAXI</a></small>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="http://finnsjourney.de">
                    <img src="gallery/finnsjourney.jpg" alt="Finn’s Journey">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Finn’s Journey</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="http://public.orsi-and-jan.info/home">
                    <img src="gallery/jan.jpg" alt="Orsi and Jan">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Orsi &amp; Jan’s Wedding</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="http://innovation.kenmore.com/explore/">
                    <img src="gallery/kenmore.jpg" alt="Kenmore Innovations">
                </a>
                <figcaption>Kenmore Innovations</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
```

However, I just can't simplified javascript. I wish to have lines that associated with 'showcase' part. The following is the full version.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').css('visibility','visible');

            // hide content until after title animation
            $('#content-wrapper').css('display','none');

            // lettering.js to split up letters for animation
            $('#title-line1').lettering();
            $('#title-line2').lettering();
            $('#title-line3').lettering();

            // TimelineLite for title animation, then start up superscrollorama when complete
            (new TimelineLite({onComplete:initScrollAnimations}))
                .from( $('#title-line1 span'), .4, {delay: 1, css:{right:'1000px'}, ease:Back.easeOut})
                .from( $('#title-line2'), .4, {css:{top:'1000px',opacity:'0'}, ease:Expo.easeOut})
                .append([
                    TweenMax.from( $('#title-line3 .char1'), .25+Math.random(), {css:{top: '-200px', right:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.from( $('#title-line3 .char2'), .25+Math.random(), {css:{top: '300px', right:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.from( $('#title-line3 .char3'), .25+Math.random(), {css:{top: '-400px', right:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.from( $('#title-line3 .char4'), .25+Math.random(), {css:{top: '-200px', left:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.from( $('#title-line3 .char5'), .25+Math.random(), {css:{top: '200px', left:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut})
                ])
                .to( $('#title-info'), .5, {css:{opacity:.99, 'margin-top':0}, delay:-1, ease:Quad.easeOut});

            function initScrollAnimations() {
                $('#content-wrapper').css('display','block');
                var controller = $.superscrollorama();

                // title tweens
                $('.title-line span').each(function() {
                    controller.addTween(10, TweenMax.to(this, .5, {css:{top: Math.random()*-200-600, left: (Math.random()*1000)-500, rotation:Math.random()*720-360, 'font-size': Math.random()*300+150}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),200);
                });
                controller.addTween(10, TweenMax.to($('#title-line1'), .75, {css:{top: 600}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),200);
                controller.addTween(10, TweenMax.to($('#title-line2'), .75, {css:{top: 200}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),200);
                controller.addTween(10, TweenMax.to($('#title-line3'), .75, {css:{top: -100}, ease:Quad.easeOut},200));

                // showcase tweens
                controller.addTween('#showcase h1', TweenMax.from( $('#showcase h1'), .75, {css:{letterSpacing:20,opacity:0}, ease:Quad.easeOut}));
                controller.addTween('#showcase p', TweenMax.from( $('#showcase p'), 1, {css:{opacity:0}, ease:Quad.easeOut}));
                $('#showcase .gallery figure').css('position','relative').each(function() {
                    controller.addTween('#showcase .gallery', TweenMax.from( $(this), 1, {delay:Math.random()*.2,css:{left:Math.random()*200-100,top:Math.random()*200-100,opacity:0}, ease:Back.easeOut}));
                });

                // hire tweens
                $('#hire h3').lettering().find('span').css('position','relative').each(function() {
                    controller.addTween('#hire h3', TweenMax.from( $(this), .25, {delay:Math.random()*.2,css:{left:Math.random()*1200-600,top:Math.random()*600-300,opacity:0}, ease:Expo.easeOut}),200);
                });
                controller.addTween('#hire p', TweenMax.from( $('#hire p'), .5, {css:{opacity:0}}));

                // individual element tween examples
                controller.addTween('#fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('#fade-it'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
                controller.addTween('#fly-it', TweenMax.from( $('#fly-it'), .25, {css:{right:'1000px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
                controller.addTween('#spin-it', TweenMax.from( $('#spin-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, rotation: 720}, ease:Quad.easeOut}));
                controller.addTween('#scale-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#scale-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, fontSize:'20px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, fontSize:'240px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
                controller.addTween('#smush-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#smush-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, 'letter-spacing':'30px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, 'letter-spacing':'-10px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), 0, 100); // 100 px offset for better timing

                // set duration, in pixels scrolled, for pinned element
                var pinDur = 4000;
                // create animation timeline for pinned element
                var pinAnimations = new TimelineLite();
                pinAnimations
                    .append(TweenMax.from($('#pin-frame-pin h2'), .5, {css:{marginTop:0}, ease: Quad.easeInOut}))
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-slide'), 1, {css:{marginLeft:0}}),
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-pin'), 1, {css:{marginLeft:'100%'}})
                    ], .5)
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-wipe'), .5, {css:{top:0}}),
                        TweenMax.from($('#pin-frame-wipe h2'), .5, {css:{marginTop:'-600px'}})
                    ], .5)
                    .append(TweenMax.from($('#pin-frame-bounce'), 5, {css:{marginTop:'-100%'}, ease:Bounce.easeOut}), .5)
                    .append(TweenMax.from($('#pin-frame-color'), .25, {css:{opacity:0}}), .5)
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color'), .25, {css:{backgroundColor:'blue'}}),
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color h2'), .25, {css:{color:'orange'}})
                    ])
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color'), .25, {css:{backgroundColor:'green'}}),
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color h2'), .25, {css:{color:'red'}})
                    ])
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color'), .25, {css:{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}),
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color h2'), .25, {css:{color:'purple'}})
                    ])
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color'), .25, {css:{backgroundColor:'orange'}}),
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color h2'), .25, {css:{color:'blue'}})
                    ])
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color'), .25, {css:{backgroundColor:'red'}}),
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color h2'), .25, {css:{color:'green'}})
                    ])
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color'), .25, {css:{backgroundColor:'#222438'}}),
                        TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-color h2'), .25, {css:{color:'#FFB000'}})
                    ])
                    .append(TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-unpin'), .5, {css:{top:'100px'}}));

                // pin element, use onPin and onUnpin to adjust the height of the element
                controller.pin($('#examples-pin'), pinDur, {
                    anim:pinAnimations, 
                    onPin: function() {
                        $('#examples-pin').css('height','100%');
                    }, 
                    onUnpin: function() {
                        $('#examples-pin').css('height','600px');
                    }
                });
                controller.pin($('#examples-2'), 3000, {
                    anim: (new TimelineLite())
                        .append(
                            TweenMax.fromTo($('#fling-it'), 2, 
                                {css:{left:-1000, top: 500, rotation: -360}, immediateRender:true}, 
                                {css:{left:2000, top: -600, rotation: 360}})
                        )
                        .append(
                            TweenMax.fromTo($('#move-it'), .75, 
                                {css:{left: -200, top: 800}, immediateRender:true}, 
                                {css:{top: -200}}),
                                -1.5 // offset for better timing
                        )
                        .append(
                            TweenMax.to($('#move-it'), .5, 
                                {css:{left: 200}})
                        )
                        .append(
                            TweenMax.to($('#move-it'), .5, 
                                {css:{top: 0}})
                        )
                        .append(
                            TweenMax.to($('#move-it'), .5, 
                                {css:{left: 0}})
                        )
                })

                // parallax example, setting duration ties animation to scroll position
                // you can target a scroll position instead of an element (whose position can change)
                controller.addTween(
                    '#examples-parallax',
                    (new TimelineLite())
                        .append([
                            TweenMax.fromTo($('#parallax-it-left'), 1, 
                                {css:{top: 200}, immediateRender:true}, 
                                {css:{top: -600}}),
                            TweenMax.fromTo($('#parallax-it-right'), 1, 
                                {css:{top: 500}, immediateRender:true}, 
                                {css:{top: -1250}})
                        ]),
                    1000 // scroll duration of tween
                );

                $('#bring-it').lettering();
                controller.addTween(
                    '#bring-it',
                    (new TimelineLite())
                        .append([
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char1'), 1, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char2'), .6, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char3'), 1.1, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char4'), .7, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char5'), .9, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char6'), 1.2, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char7'), .6, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
                            TweenMax.from($('#bring-it .char8'), .8, 
                                {css:{fontSize: 0}, immediateRender:true, ease:Elastic.easeOut})
                        ])
                        ,
                    1200,
                    -100 // offset for better timing
                );

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need from the JavaScript is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var controller = $.superscrollorama();

    // showcase tweens
    controller.addTween('#showcase h1', TweenMax.from( $('#showcase h1'), .75, {css:{letterSpacing:20,opacity:0}, ease:Quad.easeOut}));
    controller.addTween('#showcase p', TweenMax.from( $('#showcase p'), 1, {css:{opacity:0}, ease:Quad.easeOut}));
    $('#showcase .gallery figure').css('position','relative').each(function() {
    controller.addTween('#showcase .gallery', TweenMax.from( $(this), 1, {delay:Math.random()*.2,css:{left:Math.random()*200-100,top:Math.random()*200-100,opacity:0}, ease:Back.easeOut}));
    });
});
```